# Terminal - Delete All Folders Not Containing .mp3 Files

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command-line

I'm using Banshee on Linux and I have it auto-organize my music collection in folder hierarchies. When I add a new album to my Music folder, Banshee automatically moves (and renames) the mp3s and puts them into the correct Artist folder. If there is no other file in the folder, then the folder is also deleted, but if other files are present, only the mp3s are moved and the folder remains. Because of this, I have a number of folders inside my music folder that contain no mp3s, only an image file or similar ancillary file.

How would I go about removing any folder (inside the Music folder) that does not have an mp3 file inside?

For example, suppose I have the following:

```
/home/user/Music/
```

and I add the folder "Album 1 (2010)" which has mp3s and also cover art. Banshee will pull out the mp3s and put them in the proper artist folder, say:

```
/home/user/Music/Artist
```

but then the folder

```
/home/user/Music/Album 1 (2010)
```

still exists. How can I check if this folder has an mp3 in it, and if not, delete it?

I figure the answer will be a command line one, but I'm open to any suggestion. Also, it might be good to require a confirmation... just in case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on ghostdog74's answer:

```
#! /bin/bash

find -depth -type d | while read -r D
 do
 v=$(find "$D" -iname '*.mp3')
 case "$v" in
 ""  )
    echo "$D no mp3"
    # rm -fr "$D" #uncomment to use
 ;;
 esac
done
```

Let's test it on the directory structure

```
.
./deleteme
./save2
./save2/x.MP3
./save-recursive
./save-recursive/nested
./save-recursive/nested/x.mp3
./save
./save/x.mp3
```

The output is:

```
./deleteme no mp3
```

Comment: This is the magic answer, I believe. It also helped me realize that I have some files with .MP3 as the extension rather than .mp3. This script shows all those and also the non-mp3 files I am looking for.

Comment: Oh, you probably want `-iname` then to match the case-insensitive names. I've edited to include that. The various glob options in the shell should be irrelevant, since there are no actual globs being performed by the shell, so I've removed those.

Comment: yeah, the -iname switch solves the capital MP3 extension problem. And I've seen the glob options before, better go google them...

Comment: A modified form of this answer was provided over on U&L too: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98469/find-directories-without-music-files/98472#98472

Answer (score 2):

First delete not mp3 file to avid empty folder with jpg files. 
    find ! -iname '*.mp3' -type f -delete

if you wont delete empty folder

```
find -depth -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment yet, but @ghostdog74 's find command checks the current directory for mp3s in addition to the actual subdirectories, if there are no mp3s loose in /home/user/Music, it'll remove the whole tree.

If these are completely empty directories, then `rmdir *` will do the trick without any scripting needed: rmdir can't remove files or directories with files in them.

For dealing with spaces, run `IFS=$(echo -en "\b\n")` either at the top of the command or in the shell first.  This prevents variables from expanding into multiple arguments when the variable contains a space.  If you do this in the shell, you'll probably want to do something like `SAVEIFS=$IFS; IFS=...; do stuff; IFS=$SAVEIFS` so that you can get the original setting back, or just close the terminal and open a new one to get a fresh environment.

Comment: This is more appopriate as a comment on ghostdog74's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s nocaseglob
find -depth  -type d | { while read -r D;
 do
 case "$D" in
    "$DR" ) continue;;
 esac
 v=$(echo "$D"/*.mp3)
 case "$v" in
 ""  )
    echo "$D no mp3, to be deleted";;
    # rm -fr "$D" #uncomment to use
 *)
     DR=${D%/*}
     ;;
 esac
done }
```

Comment: This gives me a list of all directories containing no mp3 file. An unexpected problem, however, is that each artist folder has no mp3s itself. I ran the code to just echo the directories and just manually deleted the relatively small number of directories. Otherwise, I think I might have deleted the top level artist directories (which contain the album directories inside).

Comment: Wait...this doesn't work for folder with a space in them...let me play around with quotation marks.

Comment: put quotes then. I left it out earlier.

Comment: This finds my simon_and_garfunkel directory, which has no MP3s in it, but does have MP3s in its subfolders.

Comment: To find bottom up, you can use the `-depth` option. see my edit.

Comment: I've now edited to fix my problem. (Not sure if the `-depth` option was supposed to help with that or not. I didn't test it.)

Comment: @Ken, why are you editing my post adding another layer of redundancy and without testing ?

Comment: @ghostdog74: because I was testing it simultaneously with your addition of `-depth`. And now that I just tested, it doesn't work without the second `find` command.

Comment: @Ken, if you put a second `find` without a `maxdepth`, its going to traverse the directory again.! And there's no need to have a 2nd `find`. please don't edit the post any more. I would rather edit it myself after OP tell me his problems after using it.

Comment: @ghostdog74 `mkdir -p test/deleteme test/save test/save-recursive/nested; touch test/save/x.mp3 test/save-recursive/nested/x.mp3; cd test`. Now run the various versions of this script from inside the `test` directory. Your version will ask to delete `./deleteme`, `./save-recursive`, and `.`.

Comment: Since ghostdog74 objcets to my edits, and won't fix this himself, the proper solution is to use `find "$D" -name '*.mp3'` instead of `echo "$D"/*.mp3`.